# How do I free up memory in Singly Linked List

Tags: c, visual-studio, linked-list

Any advice on how do I free up the memory I allocated for `char *` (allocated in `CreateList` func) in `FreeList` function?

Basically, i will return the root in CreateList to FreeList function as function parameter.

I tried to use

```
temp = head;
head = head->next;
free(temp->str);        
free(temp);
```

but it fails too.

```
LIST *CreateList(FILE *fp) 
{
    /* Variable declaration */
    char input[BUFF];
    LIST *root = NULL;
    size_t strSize;    
    LIST *newList;            

    /* Read till end of file */
    while (fscanf(fp, "%255s", input) != EOF) 
    {
        strSize = strlen(input) + 1;

        /* Function to determine if we shud create a new node or increment node count */
        if (!ListSame(root, input))  
        {
            /* New node */
            if ((newList = (LIST *)malloc(sizeof(LIST))) == NULL) 
            {
                printf("Out of memory...");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            } 
           if ((newList->str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strSize))) == NULL) 
            {
               printf("Not enough memory for %s", input);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            memcpy(newList->str, input, strSize);
            newList->count = 1;
           //determine if it is root
           if (root == NULL)
           {
               newList->next = NULL;
               root = newList;
               }
               else
               {
                   newList->next = root->next;
                   root->next = newList;
               }
           }
        }
    return root;
}


  void FreeList(LIST *head)
  {
      LIST *temp = NULL;
      char* str;
      /* loop from root till end */
      while (head != NULL)
      {  
          temp = head;
          str = temp->str;
          head = head->next;
          free(str);
          free(temp);         
      }
 }
```

Comment: Edited the post, with new changes. but cant fix it too =/

Answer (score 0):

```
void FreeList(LIST *head)
{
    LIST *temp = NULL;
    /* loop from root till end */
    while (head != NULL)
    {  
       temp = head;
       head = head->next;     
       free(temp->str); /* Free the string does not matter if str is null */   
       free(temp);
       /* How do i free the dynamic allocated memory for char * */         
    }
}
```

I think you should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same principle as your existing code:

```
char* str = head->str;
if(str != NULL)
{
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: You do not need the if statement. `free(NULL)` is a noop!

Comment: Yeap. tried this before, but on the second iteration, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be worth trying (passing the address of the pointer since you are passing it to another function):

calling function: FreeList (&head)

called function: void FreeList(LIST **head)

Answer (score 0):

Your list is a recursively defined type... why don't use use recursion?

```
void FreeList(LIST *node)
{
    if (node == null) /* end of the line */
        return;
    LIST *next = node->next; /* save a copy of the next to be freed */
    /* free the contents of the current node */
    free(node->str);
    free(node);
    FreeList(next); /* free the next */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allocating memory for your strings correctly:

```
if ((newList->str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strSize))) == NULL)
```

allocates enough memory for a `size_t` type - not the number of characters needed for the string.

It should be:

```
if ((newList->str = (char *)malloc(strSize)) == NULL)
```

actually, even better would be:

```
if ((newList->str = strdup(input)) == NULL)
```

then you can also get rid of the line of code that does a `memcpy()`.

Using `strdup()` to handle common string copying in C helps prevent stupid bugs like this - which happen *all the time*.

Comment: Ah. This works!
Thanks alot. didnt realise that the problem actually at CreateList, guess i was too concentrated on FreeList function. =/